# How to force LibGDX to screen resolution on Android?

Tags: java, libgdx

No matter what type of viewport I use, the Android version of my code renders to exact resolution on the bottom left of the screen.

How do I make it occupy the whole screen realestate?

I've tried forcing the resolution to Gdx.graphics.getWidth/.getHeight, but that causes a null pointer exception

Comment: There is another issue like this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26178680/libgdx-viewport-android-devices
If it's not helpful share your code.